# Jquery Div sort and order =)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem i have is i need to group certain divs together and reorder them, and if it was all animating it would be cool. Please see below:

```
<div id="away">Some Content</div>
<div id="online">Some Content</div>
<div id="offline">Some Content</div>
<div id="away">Some Content</div>
<div id="online">Some Content</div>
<div id="offline">Some Content</div>
<div id="online">Some Content</div>
<div id="online">Some Content</div>
<div id="away">Some Content</div>
```

So i kinder need to group the id’s together the order by:
1.online
2.away
3.offline

So:

```
<div id="online">Some Content</div>
<div id="online">Some Content</div>
<div id="online">Some Content</div>
<div id="online">Some Content</div>
<div id="away">Some Content</div>
<div id="away">Some Content</div>
<div id="away">Some Content</div>
<div id="offline">Some Content</div>
<div id="offline">Some Content</div>
```

I can't seem to get my head arround this one =(.

I'm using Jquery on the rest of the site.

Any ideas =), Cheers, Sam T

Comment: While I showed how to do this below, you should generate it in the correct order from the server if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's get rid of those IDs (IDs must be unique!), and use a classes for valid HTML, like this:

```
<div id="users">
  <div class="away">Some Content</div>
  <div class="online">Some Content</div>
  <div class="offline">Some Content</div>
  <div class="away">Some Content</div>
  <div class="online">Some Content</div>
  <div class="offline">Some Content</div>
  <div class="online">Some Content</div>
  <div class="online">Some Content</div>
  <div class="away">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

Then you could sort them easily using [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), like this:

```
var statusOrder = ["online", "away", "offline"];
for(var i=0; i<statusOrder.length; i++) {
    $("#users ." + statusOrder[i]).appendTo("#users")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qrq2U/), this assumes a simple container, like `<div id="users"></div>` wrapped around this content...just use the selector of whatever container they're in.
    ​

Comment: OMG i didnt use ID did I =o.... shame.... =) thanks for this i will try it later =).

Comment: @Sam - Welcome :)  Be sure to accept answers on this and future questions via the check-mark beside the one that helped :)